# CSS file not loading / displaying in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm creating a small one page website ..for the first time in **quite a while**. 
It works fine on chrome & safari across desktop, tablet & phone but on Firefox (v20 for mac os) the CSS does not load (locally or online).

I have done some research & have checked / amended the following:

- the encoding is "utf-8"
- no difference / change when using absolute paths over relative.
- path is correct, right down to the case sensitive name of the css file.
- link type is specified (text/css)
- cache has been cleared.. alot..

.. but still no luck, below is the line of code linking to the css & it is also live on http://www.louisetiernan.com

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>
```

All help very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's probably something with the css file.
Try to remove some lines from the top and see if it help until you get to the problem.

Comment: `jQuery.n33_preloadImage = function(url, onload)` (with a very nice comment) in fade.js throws an error in console. Dunno if it's related or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have typos in your CSS. Everything beyond the first typo is not executed:

What you have:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'chaparral';
  src: url('fonts/chaparralprosemibold.eot); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'chaparralr';
  src: url('fonts/chaparralproegular.eot); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
}
```

Add the `'` just before the `)`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'chaparral';
  src: url('fonts/chaparralprosemibold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'chaparralr';
  src: url('fonts/chaparralproegular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
}
```

You forgot 2 instances of the closing `'` in the url arguments.

Comment: Thanks so much! Actually didn't realise css could cause 'compilation' style errors like that so hadn't been paying too much attention to the css in that way. Lesson Learned!

Answer (score 1):

Viewing the interpreted CSS in firebug, it appears that FF is having trouble with your `@font-face` declarations. Try removing them from `styles.css` to diagnose the problem. It's possible the interpreter doesn't like multiple `src` properties, or perhaps it is choking on the comments (although everything looks good to me [and Chrome and Safari...]).

Comment: Yip, that was it. remove the @font-face parts and it loaded fine. I know where to start now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are a number of errors in your CSS file which cause it not to be rendered correctly on the page. Please go to the following web site and validate your CSS code (paste it all right in there):

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

When I entered your css there 5 errors were located. Go through and fix each error and the css should show up and start working.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the culprit is your / at the end of your  tag.

Should look like this:

```
...type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Comment: the '/' at the end of the link tag?

Just updated to this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> & still nothing.