# Style.css not loading in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mozilla

I am working on a website that isn't loading properly on Mozilla Firefox. 
It loads great on Google Chrome, Opera and Safari but experiencing troubles loading on Mozilla and IE. 
Using Bootstrap, HTML and CSS for the website.

Website link: http://alumniapp.in

Problems being faced on Mozilla: It loads the Bootstrap Stylesheet but not my style.css.
Problems being faced on IE: Does not work at all.

Any insight is extremely helpful. This is the first problem I haven't been able to solve.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you googled it, you would've seen this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663889/stylesheet-not-loading-in-mozilla-firefox

Comment: Check this post **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391245/css-file-not-loading-displaying-in-firefox**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="style/css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine in Mozilla. Thanks for your help. Any suggestions for IE?

Comment: What version of IE you use?

Comment: I am curious how/why this worked to solve the problem.